# openldap server on ubuntu 10.0.4

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, openldap

i did install the openldap server using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install slapd ldap-utils
```

it did install successfully. Funny thing thought is that it didn't provide me an init.d file.

```
tuba@foobar:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/slapd restart
sudo: /etc/init.d/slapd: command not found
tuba@pfoobar:~$
```

Am I missing something? I was looking the "ubuntu howto" for this version https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html and all schemas that i should load, located on /etc/ldap/schema/* doesn't exist, but the directory does.

```
tuba@foobar:~$ ls -l /etc/ldap/schema/
total 0
tuba@foobar:~$
```

So Am I missing something? I'm using ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps on this link: [OpenLDAP installation steps on Ubuntu 10.10 (french)](http://www.aepik.net/documentation/annuaire/openldap/installation). It is in french, but check out commands, conf and LDIF as I done recently.

Additionnaly, you could try to reinstall packages:

> $ sudo apt-get purge slapd ldap-utils